# Why I didn't find like the question required in this Probability problem?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, permutations

I don't know where I went wrong.

Here the part of the math problem:

```
We have two boxes, U1 and U2 

U1 has: 

(n) number of white balls.

(3) number of black balls

U2 has:

(2) number of white balls.

(1) number of black balls

We do experiment E:

We take, randomly, 1 ball from U1 and we put it in U2. Then, we take 1 ball from U2 and we put it in U1

1) We consider the A probability: "After the experiment E, the two boxes stay like the way they were"

 A)Prove that the probability p(A) is written like this: p(A) = (3/4) * ( (n+2) / (n+3) )
```

And here is my solution:

```
Since the two boxes stay the way they are. That means we have to take from each box 1 ball of the same color as the other so that the number of black balls and white balls stay the same. 

So we calculate the number of probabilities for each box:

The first box: $P(1,n+1) = n+3$

The second box: P(1,4) = 12 => I thought that after putting a ball in U2 from U1, they will be four balls. 

Then I calculated like this:

P(A) = ([P(1,3)/n+3] * [P(1,2)/12]) + ([P(1,n)/n+3] * [P(1,3)/12)]

But I found it to be P(A) = (3/4) * ( (n+2) / 3(n+3) )
```

Why 3 is in there? What I have done wrong?

*Btw, I used [] so that I make it much easier to read and give priorities to the operations.*

Comment: Usually a good way to sort things like this out is to take a small, specific $n$, like $n=0$, and write it all out completely.  Hard to make a mistake with such a small system.

Comment: have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to improve your mathematical expressions.

Comment: What is $P(a,b)$ supposed to denote?  Often this notation is used for permutations, but that doesn't seem to fit with what you've written.

Comment: @NateEldredge That's correct. It's for permutations.

Comment: So how does $P(1,4) = 12$?  I would expect either 0 or 4 depending on which parameter is which.

Comment: @NateEldredge Holy shit. It's actually equal to 4. Now that it isn't equal to 12, there is no 3 anymore. And since there is no 3 anymore, the solution I have done is correct now. Thanks!

Comment: As an aside, there are many different notations for counting the number of "permutations" (*I dislike calling them that since they don't involve all available characters, partial permutations perhaps is a better name*) which counts the number of length $r$ strings with no repeated letters from an alphabet of $n$ available letters.  Some use $~_nP_r$, others $P(n,r)$.  You apparently used $P(r,n)$ which adds to the confusion.  I personally prefer $n\frac{r}{~}$ to notate this which makes writing the answer to things like the birthday problem quite clean, e.g. $1-\dfrac{365\frac{k}{~}}{365^k}$

Comment: For the time being, you should match whatever notation your teacher and/or book uses, but you should be aware of what other common notations there are to avoid confusion when reading and/or writing outside of your classroom environment, *especially* when using a notation where reversing the arguments is also accepted practice like $P(n,r)$ vs $P(r,n)$ as here.  See [Falling factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials#Alternate_notations) and [Permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Other_uses_of_the_term_permutation) on wikipedia.